# jQuery UI DatePicker - Disable all days except first and 15th day of each month

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I want to disable all days on this datepicker except the 1st and 15th of every month. I referenced this answered question, but I am only able to return one date. I'm a novice in javascript. [jQuery UI DatePicker - Disable all days except last day of month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712294/jquery-ui-datepicker-disable-all-days-except-last-day-of-month)

Any help would be great, thank you.

Comment: Ahah both answer are exactly the same, but you accepted the later one, weird :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$(function(){
    $("input").datepicker(
        {
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {

        if (date.getDate() == 15 || date.getDate() == 1) {
            return [true, ''];
        }
        return [false, ''];
       }
    });
});
```

​
Check out the link below for a working example!

http://jsfiddle.net/HM83u/

Answer (score 12):

Seems like this would work

```
$('.selector').datepicker({
       beforeShowDay: function (date) {
       //getDate() returns the day (0-31)
       if (date.getDate() == 1 || date.getDate() == 15) {
           return [true, ''];
       }
       return [false, ''];
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks you everyone, was so much easier than I was making it out to be.