# How to disable all the days in datepicker instead of provided days?

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker, yii2

I have a `datepicker`in which I am doing two operations. Firstly I try to `bold` the days which are provided in the form of `array` Secondly, I am trying to disable all the other days which are not in the provided `array`. In result of my code, all the days which are provided in the `array` are now bold but I can't able to disable other days which are not in the `array`. I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12061483/jquery-ui-datepicker-disable-all-days-except-first-and-15th-day-of-each-month) answer but it didn't works. This is my `datepicker`:

```
                    <?php
                        echo DatePicker::widget([
                            'name' => 'check_multiple_date',
                            'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_INLINE,
                            'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select issue date ...', 'id' => 'date-picker-multiple-half-hour', 'toggleActive' => true],
                            'pluginOptions' => [
                                'format' => 'dd-M-yyyy',
                                'todayHighlight' => false,
                                'multidate' => true,
                                'beforeShowDay' => new JsExpression($JsBeforeDayMultipleHalfHour)
                            ],
                        ]);
                    ?>
```

And this is my code for disable and to bold the text of those dates to which are in an `array` named `$thirty_minutes_dates`

```
$JsBeforeDayMultipleHalfHour = <<<EOF
    function(date){
        var dates = new Array();
        dates = {$thirty_minutes_dates};
        var year = date.getFullYear(), month = date.getMonth(), day = date.getDate();
        for (var i=0; i < dates.length; ++i) {
            if (year == parseInt(dates[i][0]) && month == parseInt(dates[i][1]) - 1 &&  day == parseInt(dates[i][2])) {
                return {classes: 'bold-text'};
            }
        return [false, ''];
        }
     }
EOF;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `code` for disabling and bold the text should be like this:

```
$JsBeforeDayMultipleHalfHour = <<<EOF
function(date){
    var dates = new Array();
    dates = {$thirty_minutes_dates};
    var year = date.getFullYear(), month = date.getMonth(), day = date.getDate();
    for (var i=0; i < dates.length; ++i) {
        if (year == parseInt(dates[i][0]) && month == parseInt(dates[i][1]) - 1 &&  day == parseInt(dates[i][2])) {
            return {classes: 'bold-text'};
        }
    return {classes: 'ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled'};
    }
 }
EOF;
```

Instead of returning false It must return the class which is used for disabling the days. I hope this is the correct answer.